# Coulombs Law on Quarks

Tags: electrostatics, quarks, coulombs-law

As from opinion from others the question don't seem to be clear so I did some changes.

What is 5.33...

it is 5+0.3+0.03+0.003+....

this sequence does not ends.

now if we have a ball and we need to give it a force of 5.33... J

Force should be a function of time.

But according to coulombs law the force exerted is a multiple of 5.33... .

the question is how can such a force be exerted at a instance of time.

I think now I made it clear.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. There are any number of forces that could be exerted on a quark. It seems here that you are asking what is the electric force between two quarks which are located at a distance $r$ apart. For this, you just have to use $F=\frac{kq^2}{r^2}$ with all the values as you have and that is the force. What else do you want to know?

Comment: force here is not a simple integer.It is multiple of 5.33...   .I dont understand  how does this force acts

Comment: Why does the force have to be an integer?

Comment: i really dont know.But it is  confusing for me to understand that at a particular instance of time how  this force is acted.As it is not clear how a 5.33... C force is like

Comment: I suspect you have a much bigger confusion that has nothing to do with quarks or anything. A 5.33C force is just like a 1C force except now with a different (greater) magnitude. Everything else is the same. What exactly worries you here? PS - I have no idea where you got this 5.33 number from and why this number seems to be throwing you off. If you can explain then maybe we can clarify the issue you are having.

Comment: no it is not 5.33 it is 5.33... i.e 1.6/3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35372/discussion-between-prahar-and-parth-maske).

Comment: +John Forkosh Thank You,I need to dtudy more about this.

Comment: +Prahar can you have a look at question i edited it